# What is the difference between onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) and onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)?

Tags: android, android-menu, oncreateoptionsmenu

Explain difference between `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` and `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

`onCreateOptionsMenu()` is called once.
`onPrepareOptionsMenu()` is called every time the menu opens.

---

From the [`onCreateOptionsMenu()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) documentation:

> This is only called once, the first time the options menu is displayed. To update the menu every time it is displayed, see [`onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29).

Comment: Also of note, use `invalidateOptionsMenu()` to force a reload of `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu)`.