# How can I programmatically toggle a MenuItem's visibility?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, menuitem

I am using ActionBarSherlock.

I want to change which ActionBar MenuItems are visible depending on the state of my Activity. (For instance depending on which tab is selected.)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the ActionMenu within the onCreateOptionsMenu method and store it in your activity and change any item visibility at any time...

Comment: Toggling the visibility in onCreateOptionsMenu was insufficient for me.
I needed to put the code into the "onPrepareOptionsMenu" so that the visibility could keep up to date with the current state of my app.
See [onCreateOptionsMenu vs onPrepareOptionsMenu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043631/what-is-the-difference-between-oncreateoptionsmenumenu-menu-and-onprepareoptio).
Maybe this is different b/c you use ActionBarSherlock, but I do not.

Answer (score 0):

You can add all items at the same menu and set it visible or not visible just using:

```
menu.findItem(R.id.your_item).setVisible(true/false);
```

in onPrepareOptionsMenu